# Cast date over null Id's, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
    originaltimestamp, 
    userid,
    YEAR(CAST(SUBSTR(originaltimestamp, 1, 10) AS date)) AS year,
    MONTH(CAST(SUBSTR(originaltimestamp, 1, 10) AS date)) AS month,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY originaltimestamp DESC) AS RN
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    userid IS NOT NULL 
    AND CAST(SUBSTR(originaltimestamp, 1, 10) AS date) BETWEEN date '2018-01-01' AND date '2021-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    1, 2, 3, 4
```

But now if I try to count all Id's (not null and null), I get the following

```
SELECT 
    originaltimestamp, 
    userid,
    YEAR(CAST(SUBSTR(originaltimestamp, 1, 10) AS date)) AS year,
    MONTH(CAST(SUBSTR(originaltimestamp, 1, 10) AS date)) AS month,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY originaltimestamp DESC) AS RN
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    CAST(SUBSTR(originaltimestamp, 1, 10) AS date) BETWEEN date '2018-01-01' AND date '2021-12-31'
GROUP BY 
    1, 2, 3, 4
```

I get the following error

> INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date:

Why doesn't it work when I exclude the condition

```
WHERE userid IS NOT NULL
```

And how can I count null ids?

Comment: Where is the COUNT in this query? What database product are you using? SqlServer? The error indicates that among those rows where `userid is NULL` there are some with originaltimestamp with invalid date value on their first 10 characters. you can see those by running (for SqlServer) `select originaltimestamp from table1 where isdate(substr(originaltimestamp,1,10))=0`

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please note there is a difference between `query` tag and `jQuery` tag